# Firebase Server SDK - How do I schedule a task?

Tags: android, firebase

I was told to schedule tasks **in the cloud** to do tasks to my Realtime Database in Firebase I need to use the Server SDK.

Let's say I'm saving data to the Firebase database using this code:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = ref.child("users");

Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<String, User>();
users.put("alanisawesome", new User("June 23, 1912", "Alan Turing"));
users.put("gracehop", new User("December 9, 1906", "Grace Hopper"));

usersRef.setValue(users);
```

But I want to upload this as a **task** for tomorrow. What I mean is, this will save TOMORROW instead of the instant this code gets run.

I have a `Calendar` ready:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(DAY_OF_MONTH,1); //This could be wrong, but I'm just telling you I have a Calendar ready, so ignore any errors in this code
```

So, how can I save a task using the Firebase Server SDK?  The docs don't provide a clear answer for this since the only thing I can see is saving data just like the Realtime Database.

Comment: There is currently no way to run your code to run on Firebase's servers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340542/how-to-write-custom-code-logic-when-using-firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is **no** way for you to run your code on Firebase's server. There are 2 options for you 2 solve this:

1. You could use [Firebase Queue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue) and run your code in Node.js
2. You could use a different library such as [Microsoft Azure](http://onsole.firebase.google.com/project/salawat-af7a4/database/data) (*I still haven't tried this yet, I'm not sure if it provides Job Scheduling for Android*)

However, Firebase is working on something called **Firebase Trigger**, which will solve our problem, however it is still not released with no confirmed release date.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 3rd party server (that uses the Firebase SDK, server SDK), you can poll all saved data and will call either a TImerService or a CRON JOB to have it persist the list to the Firebase Realtime Database.

It will depend on your server implementation, but a queueing implementation indicated above would work in your scenario.

An example of CRON job to call a webservice (in your case, the one that will persist all queued items to Firebase) can be found on this [StackOverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259530/using-cron-jobs-to-visit-url). For TimerService, you can refer to its [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html)

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, but your links are in another computer languge. I'm pretty sure Firebase itself has the option, as someone previously marked. +1 for trying.

Answer (score 0):

Create a broadcast reciever and define it in your manifest.
Override onRecieve and put your firebase code there. 
Then define the receiver in your manifest. 
Create a pendingIntent using the Receiver and set it in a AlarmManager, by using the setExact() method and pass in the pendingIntent.

Comment: yet you tagged it as android?